# c++ Why did commenting this code out work for my build?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working with a copy of [VES](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES). I've been dealing with this issue for a while and through trial and error I've rendered a "solution". I don't understand why it worked because I'm still a novice with `c++` so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on me. What's going on here?

## **Errors**

- `strequal.h:33:8: error: 
        expected parameter declarator
  size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz);`
- `strequal.h:33:8: error: expected ')'`
- `strequal.h:33:8: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___strlcat_chk'`

**formdata.c:39**

```
#include "strequal.h"
```

**strequal.h**

```
#ifndef __STREQUAL_H
#define __STREQUAL_H
/***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998 - 2008, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/

#include <curl/curl.h>

#define strequal(a,b) curl_strequal(a,b)
#define strnequal(a,b,c) curl_strnequal(a,b,c)

#ifndef HAVE_STRLCAT
#define strlcat(x,y,z) Curl_strlcat(x,y,z)
#endif
size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz);

#endif
```

## Hack / "Solution"

The parameter declarations all looked good and scouring the web / investigating related files I couldn't make much sense out of what was happening so after hours of researching I merely tried commenting out **strequal.h:33**

`// strequal.h:33:8: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___strlcat_chk'`

100% build

Comment: Are you calling cmake prior to compilation? `cmake -P configure.cmake`

Comment: *sans* "script mode" but yes I called `cmake`, `ccmake`, modified options (c, g, q), and finally `make -j4`. The build worked fine after commenting out the afore mentioned line.

Comment: I assumed running cmake would have detected strlcat and set HAVE_STRLCAT. Weird...

Comment: I just scanned my `make` output for any trace of `strlcat` and found nothing. How can I check to see if `HAVE_STRLCAT` was defined?

Comment: It's a bug https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1192/
Removing that line works for you because you happen to include `string.h` somehere else .. the proper fix would be to include `string.h` when `HAVE_STRLCAT` is defined or else define it through `Curl_strlcat`